# Django: detail is not showing and no error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Actually I'm try to get product details but when I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/mobiles/motorola-moto-g-16gb it is loading templates but showing nothing and even doesn't showing any error.

Note: 'mobiles' is category in url and rest is slug in Product models that you can see down.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    slug = models.SlugField(null = True, blank = True)
    imgurl = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404, Http404
from django.template import RequestContext
from cat.models import Category, Product 

def detail(request, slug, category_name_url):
try:
    category = Category.objects.get(name=category_name_url)
    product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)

except Product.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404

return render_to_response('product/detail.html', {'product': product, 'category_name': category_name_url})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from cat import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/$', views.category, name='category'),
url(r'^(?P<category_name_url>\w+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', views.detail , name='detail'),
)
```

**product/detail.html**

```
<h1>{{ object.title }}</h1>
<p> {{ object.price }}</p>
<img src="{{ object.imgurl }}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are passing 'product' in your context, you have to use 'product' in your templates.

`return render_to_response('product/detail.html', {'product': product, 'category_name': category_name_url})`

So, the template code should be:

```
<h1>{{ product.title }}</h1>
<p> {{ product.price }}</p>
<img src="{{ product.imgurl }}">
```